# why does VirtualAlloc fail for lpAddress greater than 0x6ffffffffff

Tags: winapi, 64-bit

I wanted to try seeing the limits on how "far" i can point to in 64 bit C program by trying to map very far addresses, as close to 64 bit as possible into valid memory by using VirtualAlloc.

I managed to get to `0x6ffffffffff` which is a 42 bit address, but any number above that results in failure to allocate, with error code 0x57(The parameter is incorrect).

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LPVOID mem;
    WCHAR message[] = L"Hello, World!";

    mem = VirtualAlloc (        
        (LPVOID)0x00006ffffffffff,
        4096,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE
    );

    if (mem == 0) {
        wprintf(L"%x.\n", GetLastError());
        system("pause");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memcpy(mem, message, sizeof(message));

    wprintf(L"[%llx] -> %ls\n", mem, mem);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I VirtualAlloc above `0x6ffffffffff`?

Comment: Your current CPU only has a 48 bit address space and at least on other systems (not sure about Windows) half of it is usually reserved for the kernel.

Comment: Doesn't the kernel have its' own address space to play with? are these bytes reserved for some specific purpose in my process's address space? I was considering stack, but I'm not sure how to test it.

Comment: Unsure about windows, but for Linux the stack starts at high addresses and grows down. The page you are trying to reserve may already be pinned for use as a stack page or similar. This somehow conflicts with the error code, but may still be correct if the 42 bit limit is hard coded in the alloc function

Comment: try call `GetSystemInfo` and look at `lpMaximumApplicationAddress`

Comment: @Dmitry The kernel could have its own address space, but it would be massively painful to pass data between userland and kernel, so it is generally not done. It's much easier to just reserve part of the address space for the kernel (like I mentioned, I don't know that this is what Windows does, but everyone else does it because it's just so much easier and faster). If you're wondering why it's just 48, that's because no x86 CPU implements more.

Comment: @Dmitry The kernel is mapped into the process' virtual memory to allow execution of the code without changing the page directories/tables (the kernel code is of course protected for user space execution). Certain parts of a process virtual memory space is thus allocated for the kernel. If you try to allocate at address `0`, I assume you will get an error.

Comment: @vadim_hr i got `0x7fffffeffff`.

Comment: @Dmitry - `000007FFFFFEFFFF` this is value for win7 x64. for win8.1 and win 10 this is `00007FFFFFFEFFFF` (in *0x10 time more). however i check address up to `lpMaximumApplicationAddress` allocated with no error (if range not busy). `0x0000070000000000` or say `0x000007F000000000` allocated without errors on win7. sure this error only on your comp

Comment: @RbMm It's going to be nothing more sinister than that address already being reserved.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - when address already reserved was another last error - `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` is when address really too high. may be OP test on vista ? i not check here, but begin from win7 how minimum limit is higher

Comment: it's windows 7.

Comment: @Dmitry - i dont know why you got this result, i really have another limit on win7. can advice for test use `VirtualAlloc (        
  0,
  4096,
  MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT|MEM_TOP_DOWN,
  PAGE_READWRITE
  )` - which result you got with `MEM_TOP_DOWN`

Comment: i got here `000007FFFFFA0000` in win7 and `00007FF778A00000` on win10

Comment: awkward, suddenly it works for `0x000007fffffaf000` and lower without errors(consistently).

Comment: @Dmitry - i sure that you mistake with `GetLastError()` or address. for all addresses < then `000007FFFFFEFFFF` on win7 - will be ok or another error - 487 (not 87)

Comment: @rbmm `VirtualAlloc((LPVOID)0x000007FFFFFEFFFe, 1,  MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);` fails with error 0x57. So clearly something more interesting is going on.

Comment: @Dmitry - and so what ? `0x000007FFFFFEFFFe` too high for win7. call with `000007F000000000` **twice** and check errors

Comment: 7f(0+) works fine, but it&#39;s below the limit, so I&#39;d expect it to still try finding a valid allocation slot. perhaps that&#39;s because they round rather than truncate?(No, even 0x...7f...f0 fails with 0x57

Comment: @Dmitry do you use IA64 ?

Comment: `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` yields `x86` which is odd, since the programs i ran earlier reached over 32 bits.

Comment: @Dmitry seems like windows used this space `>0x6ffffffffff` for system purposes (on IA64 architecture - it is used for Wow64 mappings) see here for details https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/11/17/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that the address you request is outside of the available range. Although there is a theoretical 64 bit range of available addresses, in practise not all of that range is available to a user mode application. You can find the allowable range by calling `GetSystemInfo` and inspecting the values of `lpMinimumApplicationAddress` and `lpMaximumApplicationAddress`. If you attempt to reserve an address outside of this range, the call to `VirtualAlloc` will fail and the error code is set to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Note that these minimum and maximum values are not precise. You will start observing `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when you get close to the limits.

Comment: my lpMaximumApplicationAddress is `0x7fffffeffff` that's `0xFFFFFF0000` under the maximum. Seems somewhat strange. If they would be reserved, would it still give error 0x57?

Comment: OK, so the explanation is surely that the address is already reserved.

Comment: if address is already reserved error will be 487 - `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. i guess some bug or hook on specific windows, because address up to `000007FFFFFEFFFF` allocated on win7+ (not check vista) and up to `00007FFFFFFEFFFF` begin from win8

Comment: so statement 2 must be *If you attempt to reserve an address that is already reserved, then the call to VirtualAlloc will fail and the error code is set to `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`*

Comment: ok it was that i was hitting the limit, but the odd thing was that i was getting error 0x57 rather than 0x487. I havent got an error 0x487 in any test yet.

Comment: @Dmitry - call VirtualAlloc twice with same address - and on second call you got this error

Comment: @RbMm I'm seeing `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when running the code in the Q on an address with `State` of `MEM_RESERVE`. I guess that's because the system says that `MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT` is invalid, but `MEM_COMMIT` would be valid.

Comment: yeah, with only MEM_COMMIT, it gives 0x1e7(487), but passing only MEM_COMMIT also doesn't allocate the memory, and even 0x(0+)6.* fails with 0x1e7

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - this is strange. i got exactly `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` when call on already allocated (or reserved) memory range. this and must be - `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` return `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES` which converted to `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. also if you call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` instead `VirtualAlloc` you got not `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` but `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_5` for example which exactly say which parameter is invalid. but i sure you mistake somewhere (not view your code) - `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` **not depended** from address state - only from your src code.

Comment: `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` this when your code (how you call api) is invalid, independent from address **state** (but depended from address **value** (if it too low or high)). the `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` this is when code is **valid** but address is busy. this is very different by sense errors.

Comment: @RbMm Hmm, I can reproduce what you say. But also, this program `#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    LPVOID mem;
    SYSTEM_INFO si = { 0 };
    LPVOID addr;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    wprintf(L"%p\n", si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
    addr = (LPVOID)((long long)si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress - 10*4096);

    mem = VirtualAlloc(addr, 4096, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (mem == 0) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        wprintf(L"Fail %d\n", err);
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: produces this output: `00007FFFFFFEFFFF
Fail 87`

Comment: When I inspect that address with `VirtualQuery` the `State` is `MEM_RESERVE`. So yeah, I don't really know what is going on here!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - this is exactly because address **value** near `lpMaximumApplicationAddress` is still not valid for virtual allocation. not **state** but **value**. if you use say `-100*4096` you got another result. the `lpMaximumApplicationAddress` not exactly limit but around. exist also user probe address, which bit smaller

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, I've modified my answer, but it feels uncomfortable because you know so much more. I'd be very happy if you edited my answer, or provided your own better answer.

Comment: sorry, all is ok. no matter, from my view, who is write answer. i have serrious problem with english :) i simply try noting that error value really have frequently more sence. and if more anylize it can understand - are problem with source code (how api is called or value by self is invalid) or problem with concrete state for given address. so need think on error. but edit really hard for me due language problems and private style

Comment: `You will start observing ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when you get close to the limits` - now (up to win 10 ) exactly on 64K. exist [`MM_HIGHEST_VAD_ADDRESS ((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)MM_HIGHEST_USER_ADDRESS - (64 * 1024)))`](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/mm/mi.h#L108) and *VirtualAlloc* return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when `lpAddress` or `lpAddress + dwSize` > `MM_HIGHEST_VAD_ADDRESS` - https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/mm/allocvm.c#L394